# How can I select object in hierarchy in Unity via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, selection

```
    private void CheckingSelection() {
    Transform child = Selection.activeTransform;
    Transform[] patchesTransform = builder.GetLevelEditorPatchesTransform();

    foreach (var parent in patchesTransform) {
        if (child.IsChildOf(parent) && child != parent) {
            Debug.Log("Set active " + parent.gameObject);
            Selection.activeGameObject = parent.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I do, but it does not select the parent. What am I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The deal is how I called method CheckingSelection();

I added this method to delegate Selection.selectionChanged. And I thought its kind of logical things to do my checking after selecting something. But it was not working. It might be of internal Unity things, that block recursy or some.

So, I addedCheckingSelection() method to EditorApplication.update delegate, and it works.